# What is the best way to use Google Assistant to call another API (e.g. Jenkins API)?

Tags: jenkins, actions-on-google

I'm working on an app to use Google Assistant to call another system (For example, ask a Jenkins server to do a build)

What is the best way to use Google Assistant to call an external API (e.g. Jenkins API) to do something (e.g. to do a build or disable a job)?

Should I start with google-assistant-sdk and build the app in Python?

Comment: You've answered your own question here. Yes, use the SDK. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Actions on Google](http://actions.google.com). It is the conversational platform that allows you to create an app that works on your phone and Google Homes.

You can set it up as a webhook with an intermediary system to do NLP like [Dialogflow](http://dialogflow.com). Your webhook can query your Jenkins status and return results.

The interaction model would be like this:

> You: Talk to My Jenkins Server
>   Google: Ok, getting My Jenkins Server
>   App: Hello. How can I help?
>   Me: Start a build
>   App: Okay, starting build 37. Later, ask me about the status of build 37.
>   Google: *beep boop* (ends conversation)

The Google Assistant SDK is meant for embedded / IoT devices.

Comment: Thanks for the info. One more questions. Is there a way to limit who can use my action? (i.e. limit who can run my action while I'm testing my app or even after I deploy my app). I don't see any way to set access from the "Welcome to Actions on Google" page.

Comment: I guess I might be able to put the access limitation in the webhook, but it will be nice to block users at the beginning, then they will not be able to crack my action or my Jenkins server

Comment: You can keep the project in test mode and share the project with others. You could also implement account linking to cut off access to anyone not allowed.